# LUIS and botframework not working: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am running the sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot by following the instructions. But when I test bot in Bot Emulator, I got `TurnError`
and  `"Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."` How do I fix this?

Here are the debug messages shown in visual studio after I sent "Hello": https://gist.github.com/wendingp/bebf9caa7643c389a08c7cf67f0a6fcd. (The welcome card works well so I didn't include those messages)

Comment: Can you verify if you have provided the correct LUIS credentials along with the bot Id and password? Did you get any error on Visual Studio?

Comment: @ranusharao what is the bot ID and password? I've updated the messages in the question

Comment: its the Microsoft App Id and password. What value have you provided for LuisAPIHostName? It should be in the format "<region>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com". I tested the sample on my end and it works as expected.

Comment: @ranusharao I added Microsoft App Id and password but still the same. It's westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

Comment: @ranusharao I finally fixed it and answered it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be published to the **production slot** instead of the **staging slot**.